# Programmatic view visible in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am programmatically creating a view with a custom object in Objective-C. It works great in the simulator but when I run the same code on my iPhone 6s Plus, it doesn't render the row. It does render programmatic rows created later in the code using the same object.

```
SalesTrackerDailyRow *thisRow = [[SalesTrackerDailyRow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yOffset, 375.0, 26)];
thisRow.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ZN%@",[zoneDict valueForKey:@"ZoneID"]];
thisRow.objLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[[[zoneDict objectForKey:@"DetailSubtotals"] objectForKey:@"MonthEndProjectionDetail"] objectForKey:@"Objective"] floatValue]]];
thisRow.actLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[[[zoneDict objectForKey:@"DetailSubtotals"] objectForKey:@"MonthEndProjectionDetail"] objectForKey:@"Actual"] floatValue]]];
thisRow.varLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[[[zoneDict objectForKey:@"DetailSubtotals"] objectForKey:@"MonthEndProjectionDetail"] objectForKey:@"Variance"] floatValue]]];
[thisRow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[thisRow.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[thisRow.objLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[thisRow.actLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[thisRow.varLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

if ([thisRow.actLabel.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    thisRow.varLabel.text = @"n/a";
}
if ([thisRow.varLabel.text containsString:@"-"]) {
    thisRow.varLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
[viewSummary addSubview:thisRow];
```

I am stumped at this point.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you adding viewSummary to the view ? i.e [self.view addSubview:viewSummary];

Comment: Have you tried examining the view in the View Debugger while the app is running on your phone? Are its frame and visibility what you expect?

Comment: Yes, I've tried.  Works great when I'm connected to my laptop.  I can only replicate the issue sporadically on my device.